# Does Dialogflow (Google) collect and store the input data?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I'm considering using Dialogflow in my company but I am not fully convinced about security issues. Does anyone of you know if Google stores any input data that comes from users? In particular, any sensitive personal data?

Thank you in advance!

Best,
Marcin

Comment: i think it does.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent sensitive personal data being stored, you can disable interaction logging entirely within your Dialogflow agent's settings. See [Interaction logging](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/interaction-logging).

Comment: The page linked above no longer has any mention of "Disable Interaction Logs". In fact, I cannot find such an option anymore...

Answer (score 0):

Nothing like this is mentioned anywhere. To be entirely safe though, I'd suggest to have a look at the [DialogFlow Enterprise version](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/). It's under the GCP so all the data are certainly safe and private.